# Windows stop responding but doesn't freeze

Tags: windows, laptop, freeze, desktop

For a few days, I've been struggling to find out why some of my friends' Windows stops responding but doesn't freeze.

It's a weird situation where, suddenly and randomly, their Windows stops responding to "new actions" (like they can't open any program - including CTRL + ALT + DEL - and they loose Internet access.

Although, it doesn't freeze. They are able to expand/minimize the already opened programs.

The symptoms are always the same, although they occurred in different places (different internet providers, different WiFi). Also, the configurations are completely different:

- `Windows 10, Desktop, x64`,
- `Windows 7, Desktop, x64`,
- `Windows 8, Laptop, x64`

and it even happened inside a virtual machine running Windows 7.

Does anyone knows what it can be? I'm thinking it could be some kind of virus, although I couldn't find anything related to it on Google and Antivirus / ADW Cleaner scans couldn't find anything either.

Comment: Seriously, if it "***Stops Responding***" then I would think that would be classified implicitly as a "***Freeze***" so I'm not sure how to visualize what you are saying is happening. Other than maybe Explorer stops responding but perhaps already opened apps respond to being minimized, maximized, manipulated, etc. Too broad as your guess is as good as my guess is as good as the next person's guess. You'd likely need to provide a ton more diagnostic logs, details, etc. of what you've already tried and/or eliminated as the cause... commonalities, or anything.

Comment: So if apps are responding within the Windows OS, then that means the Windows OS is not freezing so what is not responding exactly when you experience this problem with other apps, etc. do respond...

Comment: I'd blame some software installed on all these PCs.

Comment: On such different computes with symptoms that you have described to be so similar, this question is way to broad for us to answer besides to say that you should look for common software or common things about the computer to isolate and diagnose.

Comment: For the VM (as it will have less personal info) configure it as follows:
1. Reduce the memory as much as possible such that it's usable but still has the issue, for Windows 7, 512MB might be enough.
2. Configure it to create a full memory dump. http://symc.ly/2vLMh7d 
3. Configure it for crash on ctrl-scroll  - http://bit.ly/2wipy4c
4. Next time it's in the state force a crash, on reboot gather \windows\memory.dmp and zip it up.
5. Share it with a file sharing service so we can analyze it.

Comment: I'd just [blame it on the rain](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BI5IA8assfk&list=RDBI5IA8assfk#t=20), ya... ya...